# Python cartesian product not working as desired with master list

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a cartesian product list of all possible combinations between two lists, made from a master list.  But passing the "master_list" into the cartesian product function.

I want the results:

(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(0, 3)
(0, 4)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
(1, 2)
(1, 3)
(1, 4)

```
x = [0,1]
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

This works (below) in displaying desired results:

```
mylist = list(itertools.product(x, y))
```

However, this doesn't work (below), and this is what I really need.  The "master_list" list might be comprised of multiple lists dynamically.  What am I missing here?:

```
master_list = [x, y]
mylist = list(itertools.product(master_list))
```

The list "master_list" is being created dynamically within the code, so I can't type something like this below.  This example also works to show what I need.

```
mylist = list(itertools.produuct(master_list[0], master_list[1]))
```

Comment: How does `master_list` actually looks like? It could just be a problem of "flattening" a *list of lists*? (converting a list of lists into a list)?

Comment: What master_list looks like should be above.  It is just a list that contains x list and y list.  Can you see the line that says "master_list = [x, y]"?  Thank you for your help.  I must be missing something obvious here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [unpack](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-parameter_list_starargs) it.

```
list(itertools.product(*master_list)))
```